# Difficulty programming SQL Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I am very new to SQL and can not get my head around using alias but i know its what i need for this solution.

I have a table called `tbl_MachineData`
Within it i have several fields including `Date`, `RunStatus`, `StartDate` and `StopDate`

What i need to do i guess via a stored procedure is the following....

```
Where RunStatus = False And StartDate Is Null And StopDate Is Null Then

Set StartDate = Date on current record

Set StopDate = Date on next record
```

This is very close for stop date but enters the the date from the row before instead of the row after

CASE WHEN dbo.tbl_MachineData.RunStatus = 0 THEN t.Date ELSE NULL END

Comment: Any particular RDBMS?

Comment: Which database? and how exactly do you determine the _next_ record?

Comment: how you are distinguish current and next as well as which DB you are using?

Comment: SQL Express 12, records are distiguished by a unique ID

Comment: Sorry, don't know what RDBMS means

Comment: you are working with a [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=RDBMS) but you don't know what it means?

Comment: yep thats true, had to google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do what you want:

```
select md.*,
       (select top 1 date
        from tbl_MachineData md2
        where md2.id > md.id
        order by md2.id
      ) as next_stopdate
from tbl_MachineData md
Where RunStatus = False And StartDate Is Null And StopDate Is Null ;
```

This should return what you want in a `select` query.

Comment: Every Next Stop Date is Null with this query?

Comment: Does it matter if i am using datetime, i don't think it should?

Comment: Oh, noticed the obvious error, should be date and not stopdate in the select

select md.*,
       (select top 1 date
        from tbl_MachineData md2
        where md2.id > md.id
        order by md2.id
      ) as next_stopdate
from tbl_MachineData md
Where RunStatus = False And StartDate Is Null And StopDate Is Null ;

Answer (score 0):

Amended code....

select md.*,
       (select top 1 date
        from tbl_MachineData md2
        where md2.id > md.id
        order by md2.id
      ) as next_stopdate
from tbl_MachineData md
Where RunStatus = False And StartDate Is Null And StopDate Is Null ;